# maps engine layers won't show on iOS or Android tab

Tags: ios, maps

We created a route with google maps engine. When i open this route with the 'embed' option on a desktop i succesfully see the route and all other layers.
However... when i open the same link on my iPad (safari & Chrome) or on a Samsung Tab i can't see the layers.

Does anyone know why i this is happening and how i can solve this?

[image: Route shown on a desktop computer]

[image: Route shown on an iPad]

I hope someone can help...

Kind regards,
Mijno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We couldnt find an actual reason or answer, but... When we add another administrator the problem was fixed! So adding the user somehow resets the security settings.